# Mac Mail program randomly reorders my accounts

Tags: macos, catalina, mail.app, gmail

I use the Mac Mail program and have multiple mail accounts (~15) - mostly gmail but a couple of non-gmail accounts. For some reason, Mail periodically (sometimes once every few days, sometimes multiple times a day) reorders the mailboxes. So on the left side where the individual account inboxes are listed under the overall Inbox tab, they'll start off correctly ordered, and then randomly - poof - they're in a random order. Well - not completely random - often it appears to be almost half-randomized. I've even gone so far as to put numerical prefixes on them so that I know the correct order and can re-order them quickly. Does anyone know what causes the Mac Mail program to do this?

And when I say "reordered", I mean the order in the mail app, in the leftmost Mailboxes pane of the Message Viewer.  As far as I can tell, there is no "order" in the System Preferences Internet Accounts tab.  It puts everything in alphabetic order (grouped by mail service).  I'm not gonna bother screenshot'ing it because I'd have to black out most everything for privacy reasons and the above should be clear enough.

Update: and it seems over the past few days, I've seen a new, possibly related, behavior.  Twice now I've seen an account go missing in my Mailbox list (i.e. the list of accounts under the Inbox tab in the left most pane).  If I closed and reopened the Mail program, it shows up again.

For what its worth, I am running v10.15.5 (Update: now 10.15.6), but this occurred with at least one prior version (and maybe several).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which is your macOS version?

Comment: version 10.15.5

Comment: When you say the "accounts" get reordered, can you confirm.  Mail obtains is account from *System Preferences → Internet Accounts.*   Where are you seeing this "reorder."  can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Updated the question with a bit more info - but for what it's worth, Mail.app is the one with the 'order', it seems.  Internet Accounts does not let you order them in there - it is all alphabetic, grouped by mail service..

Comment: I've had a very similar problem for years. If you made any changes at all to your accounts, mail would re-order them in alphabetical order. I had to keep a screen shot of proper order on hand, it was so annoying. But for me this problem finally stopped around High Sierra or Mojave. Not sure why yours is doing it, but I agree the disappearing account is probably a trigger for it.

Comment: Can you see a correlation between the mysterious sorting and the date/timestamps of the most recent messages _in_ each mailbox? Perhaps the mailboxes are somehow reordering based on the most recent incoming  messages.

Comment: No, no correlation between timestamps of most recent messages.  Only a few of the accounts get mail on a regular basis, but they all seem subject to potential randomization.